# make without makefile after cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake

I try to use the c++ language bindings for the ev3dev lego brick: https://github.com/ddemidov/ev3dev-lang-cpp

The instruction is as follows:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DEV3DEV_PLATFORM=EV3
make
```

I am running windows and have cmake and mingw available. After running cmake it creates some files in the `build` directory. However: There is no makefile which could be picked of by make. So I am wondering how iam supposed to compile these bindings

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Windows, CMake generates a MSVC solution by default. Check for a `.sln` file in your build directory.

The instructions you linked are assuming a Unix-ish platform, where the default is to create Makefiles.

If you actually *want* Makefiles on Windows, add `-G "Unix Makefiles"` to the `cmake` line.

If you want to use MSVC as compiler *but work on the command line*, another option is `-G "NMake Makefiles"`, and calling `nmake` after that.

Make sure to delete your build directory before trying to build a new generator target. CMake can be touchy about that.

Check `cmake --help` for a list of available options. (Especially the generator targets are platform-specific.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - but how can I change that behavior?

Comment: @Fuzzyma: Added. Sorry, I missed the part of the question stating Windows. (The pitfalls of cross-reading.)

Comment: wow all these edits :D. Thank you! That helped a lot. However I will need to create a follow up question since I want these bindings to be cross compiled for the brick (with Sourcery CodeBench) which is not working because unix headers are missing...